# Root finding using Newton's method with quadratic interpolation - Is there a mistake in this textbook?

Tags: newton-method, rootfinding

I've been trying to learn about root finding using Newton's method, which uses a quadratic interpolating polynomial. I found this text, [Numerical methods for roots of polynomials, PART 2: McNamee & Pan](https://www.elsevier.com/books/numerical-methods-for-roots-of-polynomials-part-ii/mcnamee/978-0-444-52730-1), which has relevant theory, but there seems to be some error in the text.

[image: Book section describing the quadratic part of Newton's method]

While calculating $x_{i+1}$, shouldn't the second term in the RHS of that equation be reciprocal of what it is, or am I wrong? I don't understand what am I missing here.

Answer (score 3):

No, the book is right. I know that the second term on the right looks superficially like the standard solution of a quadratic equation, upside down, but look more closely: the denominator $2f(x_i)$ is $2c$, not the $2a$ which you might have expected.

Muller's method uses a less common expression for the roots of a quadratic equation:
$$
x = \frac{-2c}{b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}
$$
which is mentioned on [the Wikipedia page for quadratic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation). They even mention there that it is used in Muller's method. And on [the Wikipedia page for Muller's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%27s_method) they say that the standard formula for a quadratic equation is not used because it may lead to a loss of significance.

I'm not sure that Muller's method is the go-to method for this kind of root finding. [Inverse quadratic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_quadratic_interpolation) is used within the standard Brent method for locating roots. I don't know enough about the topic to explain in more detail, however.